# MySQL sort data on certain values

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL view code that sorts certain values on top of their group and the other values alphabetically:

```
SELECT 
    `country`.`iso3` AS `iso3`,
    `country`.`iso2` AS `iso2`,
    `country`.`name_en` AS `name_en`,
    `country`.`name_fr` AS `name_fr`,
    IF((`country`.`continent_en` <> 'Africa'),
        'International',
        `country`.`continent_en`) AS `continent_en`,
    IF((`country`.`continent_fr` <> 'Afrique'),
        'International',
        `country`.`continent_fr`) AS `continent_fr`,
    `country`.`flag_address` AS `flag_address`
FROM
    `country`
ORDER BY IF((`country`.`continent_en` <> 'Africa'),
    'International',
    `country`.`continent_en`) , FIELD(`country`.`name_en`, 'International') DESC , `country`.`name_en`
```

It works fine on local, but when I try it online the first values of each group are stripped.

On local, it gives the Africa "country" record on top of the Africa continent countries and the International "country" record on top of the International continent. Online those two records are missing. How can I fix this.

Thanks

On local I run MySQL 57, online it's MySQL 56.

Comment: Ordering has no effect on which rows are shown (unless you use `LIMIT`). If those records are missing, they must not be in the table.

Comment: I selected the wrong table. My bet.

Answer (score 0):

I selected the wrong table. My bet.